# Example Spotify api audio analysis CURL command works, but when I enter a new song ID it does not - what is the correct command?

Tags: curl, spotify

curl -X GET "https://api.spotify.com/v1/audio-analysis/3JIxjvbbDrA9ztYlNcp3yL" -H "Authorization: Bearer {your access token}"

The above song "3JIxjvbbDrA9ztYlNcp3yL" works when I execute the curl command with my access token. However when I try the command with this song it does not:

```
artist: 
"Red Hot Chili Peppers"
id: 
"4"
maxEmotion: 
"anger"
score: 
"0.578864"
song: 
"Suck My Kiss"
spotifyCode: 
"spotify:track:0psB5QzGb4653K0uaPgEyh"
```

What should the CURL command be for this? I have tried with and without the 'spotify:track' parts but I get the same error:

```
-bash: https://api.spotify.com/v1/audio-analysis/0psB5QzGb4653K0uaPgEyh: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There must have been a formatting error as this CURL command works:

```
curl -X GET "https://api.spotify.com/v1/audio-analysis/3JIxjvbbDrA9ztYlNcp3yL" -H "Authorization: Bearer BQCKstphV3lZkcjVVF1gDYueqltYUsKCKXXUVeKA8NKBJam_bsyc0ee15FyDBszeGsIbO77DU031jsKpHSwWIWMjOBdUyxMf5gjhDdhVrwZ_Z9f_MZwNDWpPII-W5z"
```

Notes: Remember to check each line after copying and pasting various codes into the command since sometimes other parts of the command get shifted, deleted or replaced accidentally!